# no access to object attributes of an object list python

Tags: python-2.7

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):

        self._att_1 = "a"
        self._att_2 = "b"

    def set_1(self, ein):
        self._att_1 = ein

    def get_1(self):
        return self._att_1

    def set_2(self, zwei):
        self._att_2 = zwei

    def get_2(self):
        return self._att_2


class B:

    def __init__(self):
        self.liste = []         # stores A. Objects
        self._att_x = 1

    def set_elem(self, el):
        self.liste.append(el)

    def get_liste(self):
        return self.liste

    def set_Att(self, x):
        self._att_x

    def get_ATT(self):
        return self._att_x



def main():

    a = A()
    aa = A()
    aaa = A()

    b = B()
    b.set_elem(a)
    b.set_elem(aa)
    b.set_elem(aaa)

    for i in b.get_liste():
        print i  # <<<--------- Why i can`t access to the A() members ?? Like i.get_1() 

## --------------------------------------------------- output
<__main__.A instance at 0x7f2f6c3ff7e8>
<__main__.A instance at 0x7f2f6c3ff830>
<__main__.A instance at 0x7f2f6c3ff878>
```

## --------------------------------------------------------

I'm trying to look at the member attributes of the objects stored in the list of B(). but I can't. The objects are in the list (see output). How do I get the attributes of the list objects or can I access them? Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not able to recreate this. Your code worked for me when replacing the `print i` with `print i.get_1()`. Are you getting errors? Because it should be printing 3 a's based on what you have written

Comment: Yeah shame on me, that i forgot that pycharm can not show the respective attributes of the objects by returning a list of objects and thats why i was thinking that it might not be possible to access the members this way. Thanks for comment

Comment: Added my comment as an answer if you wanted to verify and vote that would be cool :D

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to recreate this. Your code worked for me when replacing the `print i` with `print i.get_1()`. Because it should be printing 3 a's based on what you have written.